# weird intranet app vb.net behavior: search results invisible when searched from different client machines

Tags: vb.net, search, intranet

The issue I'm trying to fix is to make the search results visible for all authorized users belonging to an Active Directory group. The intranet app was programmed in VB.NET using web forms, the DB is on SQLServer and IBM iSeries.  Users are generally using IE. Those users are authorized for this app.

Some users can see the search results when logged in on their workstation. Other users see no results when logged in on their local machine, but can see results when logged in remotely on the host server thus accessing the app as localhost and the correspoding port.

As this is a web application, I don't see how the client machine would affect displaying the results, provided they are fetched corretly from the DB. On my developer machine I see results. When logged in on a test laptop, I can't see the results.

What can be different in terms of client machine configuration, that cause such weird behavior?

Comment: Could it be a case of [credential double hopping issues](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx)?  I don't know why it would work from some machines and not others, but may be related?  Either way, you ought to be able to do some logging/debugging on the server - if it's a credential issue, there should be some exceptions

Comment: Well, the article you mentioned is about  a method of maintaining the client's Kerberos authentication credentials over two or more connections. My case was about an intranet app, no Kerberos authentication. Secondly, my issue was client-related, IE in particular. Thanks, anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, the application worked in Chrome, but not in IE. By debugging it, the error I got was SCRIPT5022:  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from thje server could not be parsed. It turned out to be an Ajax issue, a limitation of the technology. The solution was to move the Search button outside the Update panel area. I hope this might help someone else someday as well.